# How to set Multiple Langues support into android application

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi am doing one application here i need to enter some  into edittext  and that data after button click i need to save in database,up to here my code is working fine.but problm is in another activity listview i have 10 languages if user select french,that time if enter data in edittext that time  i need to write data in  edit text in french format and save data in data base also french format..or else user select hindi means i need to write  data in edit text in hindi format and save data in data base also hindi format.but in my app default languge is english,please how i have to do this suggest me...

```
   Language.class: 
   public class Language extends Activity {

 RelativeLayout main,sub;
public void setNoTitle() {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
} 
 float screenHeight,screenWidth,screendensity;
 TextView heading;
 Button back;
 private ListView lv;
 private EditText et;
 private String listview_array[] = { "Arabic", "Dutch", "English", "French", "German",
 "Hindi", "Italian", "Japanese", "Portuguese", "Russian" };
 private ArrayList<String> array_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
 int textlength=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setNoTitle();
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
     screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
     screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
     screendensity = displaymetrics.densityDpi;
    setContentView(R.layout.language);

      lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
         et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
         lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));

         et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
         {
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
         {
                                                                         // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
         }
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
         int start, int count, int after)
         {
         // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
         }
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
         int start, int before, int count)
         {
         textlength = et.getText().length();
         array_sort.clear();
         for (int i = 0; i < listview_array.length; i++)
         {
         if (textlength <= listview_array[i].length())
         {
         if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
         (String)
         listview_array[i].subSequence(0,
         textlength)))
         {
                                                                                                                         array_sort.add(listview_array[i]);
                                                                                                         }
                                                                                         }
                                                                         }
         lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
         (Language.this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));
         }
         });

         lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String 


                if (language.equals("English US")) {

                } else if (language.equals("Francais")) {

                } else if (language.equals("Espanol")) {

                }
            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: you need to cteate values for different Languages. like values-it(For Italy) values-de(German) and in your strings.xml define all the string used in your app w.r.p to all languages in each folder.

Comment: okey.i tried that one also.but what i want is in editext , text enter by the user should be changed and data in whole application